# 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, коллекции

Все было нормально, пока не стал добавлять аннотации для `Sptring-MVC`. Все поля, в том числе и поле `List` не сообщали о какой-либо ошибке. В чем может быть проблема? В паутине есть вариант с тем, чтобы добавить `*@Basic*` на переменной, но это не помогает, так же как и `*@OneToMany*`.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customer extends User {

    public Customer(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Customer(String name, String lastName){ // Пользовательский конструктор создается,
        super(name, lastName);                     // когда нам нужно создать новый экземпляр,
    }                                              // но у нас еще нет ID.


    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private double wallet;

    private List<Order> orderList;// ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТ КРАСНЫМ И ПИШЕТ 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container



    // Методы
    public void depositMoney(){// Внести деньги на счет

        }

    public void withdrawMoney(){// Вывести деньги со счета

        }

    public void makeOrder(){// Сделать заказ

        }
}
```

Comment: `Order` тоже является `entity`?

Comment: пока что нет! но в будущем планирую

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OneToMany` работает только с `entity`.

Соответственно, Вам нужно из `Order` тоже сделать сущность.

Допустим, у Вас две `entity`: `Customer` и `Order`, между которыми связть типа один-ко-многим(one-to-many), Вам нужно указать hibernate на это. Для этого в классе `Customer` поле `orderList` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Order> orderList;
```

Тогда в сущности Order нужно сделать поле:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonBackReference
private Customer customer;
```

А теперь по порядку - `OneToMany` и `ManyToOne` указывают на тип связи между двумя сущностями.

`fetch type` - советую почитать про это отдельно, грубо говоря - это то как hibernate будет получать данные.

`cascade type` - там много составных параметров,если `all` - то объекты каскадно сохраняютс, удаляются, обновляются и т.д.

`@JsonBackReference` и `@JsonManagedReference` - аннотации, нужные чтобы избежать бесконечной рекурсии(в `Customer` есть список `Order` в каждом из `Order` есть `Customer` в котором список `Order`...) тут же обратная ссылка в случае зависимого поля(`private Customer customer`) заменяется на `customer_id`

Comment: а что за mappedBy?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan это имя поля, на которое Вы ссылаетесь(я забыл исправить название, уже пофиксил)

Comment: а если объект это обычный стринг, а всё равно выдаёт ошибку точь в точь?